# Running tomcat from another connected pc

Tags: apache, http, networking, tomcat, servlets

I want to test some pages on several machine.

I have tomcat running on one pc lets say PC1 and several pc are connected to PC1. I want other pc to load the one page from PC1. I have tried some alternatives but it is not working

Does anyone know about this??

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Troubleshooting**
From PCX try pinging PC 1: `ping PC1`
If that succeeds try doing telnet to Tomcat port (default 8080): `telnet PC1 8080`
That's probably where it will fail, refusing to connect to 8080.

**Alternative 1**
You have a Firewall blocking the the other PC to access Tomcat port (default 8080).

**Alternative 2**
Tomcat is binded to localhost only, and you can't access it from another host.

Look for the tomcat/conf/server.xml file and look for some text like:

```
<Connector 
    port="8080" 
    protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
    address="127.0.0.1"
    ...
```

If you find the address attribute, remove it and it should bind to every ip address.